# search and replace single quote and backslash using jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have the following codes:

```html
<c:set var="myContent" value="${row.content}"/>
<c:set var="search" value="'" />
<c:set var="replace" value="\\'" />
<c:set var="myContent" value="${fn:replace(myContent, search, replace)}"/>
        
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
    window.addEventListener("load", function(){
        element.innerHTML='${myContent}';
    }, true);
</script>
```

It only replaced single quote character only, what if I also want to replace backslash (\)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally manage the problem with the following codes:

```
    <c:set var="myContent" value="${row.content}"/>
    <c:set var="singlequote" value="'"/>
    <c:set var="backslash" value="\\"/>
    <c:if test="${fn:contains(myContent, singlequote) && !fn:contains(myContent,backslash)}">
            <c:set var="search" value="'" />
            <c:set var="replace" value="\\'" />
            <c:set var="myContent" value="${fn:replace(myContent, search, replace)}"/>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${fn:contains(myContent, backslash) && !fn:contains(myContent,singlequote)}">
            <c:set var="search" value="\\" />
            <c:set var="replace" value="\\\\" />
            <c:set var="myContent" value="${fn:replace(myContent, search, replace)}"/>
    </c:if>
    <c:if test="${fn:contains(myContent, singlequote) && fn:contains(myContent,backslash)}">
            <c:set var="search" value="\\"/>
            <c:set var="replace" value="\\\\" />
            <c:set var="myContent" value="${fn:replace(myContent, search, replace)}"/>
            <c:set var="find" value="'"/>
            <c:set var="change" value="\\'" />
            <c:set var="myContent" value="${fn:replace(myContent, find, change)}"/>
    </c:if>


    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
          window.addEventListener("load", function(){
            element.innerHTML='${myContent}';
            }, true);
     </script>
```

Comment: You are repeating <c:set var="singlequote" value="'"/> and <c:set var="backslash" value="\\"/> with <c:set var="search" value="'" />. Try minimizing the code

Comment: And this is one reason that we moved to thymeleaf, despite the a cost of converting a jsp project to thymeleaf.

Comment: This screams for a custom EL function. Way cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in the above code, instead of c:if we should use the c:when because sequence matters here, have a look at the below one

```
<c:set var="myContent" value="${row.content}"/>
<c:set var="singlequote" value="'"/>
<c:set var="backslash" value="\\"/>

<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${fn:contains(myContent, singlequote) && fn:contains(myContent,backslash)}">
        <c:set var="search" value="\\"/>
        <c:set var="replace" value="\\\\" />
        <c:set var="myContent" value="${fn:replace(myContent, search, replace)}"/>
        <c:set var="find" value="'"/>
        <c:set var="change" value="\\'" />
        <c:set var="myContent" value="${fn:replace(myContent, find, change)}"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${fn:contains(myContent, singlequote) && !fn:contains(myContent,backslash)}">
        <c:set var="search" value="'" />
        <c:set var="replace" value="\\'" />
        <c:set var="myContent" value="${fn:replace(myContent, search, replace)}"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${fn:contains(myContent, backslash) && !fn:contains(myContent,singlequote)}">
        <c:set var="search" value="\\" />
        <c:set var="replace" value="\\\\" />
        <c:set var="myContent" value="${fn:replace(myContent, search, replace)}"/>
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
    
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
      window.addEventListener("load", function(){
        element.innerHTML='${myContent}';
        }, true);
 </script>
```